# mvc bundling, one per view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I am working with mvc4 and exploring how bundling of css and javascript works. I have a question that I need assistance with.

For every page (view) I render I would like to just have one js and css file. This is a culmination of the multiple files that are required for that view. From what I have seen, I can create bundles of files but I did not see a way of creating a bundle for each view.

Could someone help me out with this, if it is possible to achieve what I outlined?

Answer (score 1):

Be more specific with your question. Show us what you tried. You have to create each of the bundles manually. If you want a bundle to be used on a specific view, create such a bundle and specify in a view that you will use that bundle there just like you specify in a view that you will be using a css file there.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is go to Static>App_Start>BundleConfig.cs :

[image: Bundle Config path]

and then create a bundle for each view you have:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/GlobalScripts")
                            .Include("~/Static/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"
                                    , "~/Static/Scripts/json2.js"
                                    , "~/Static/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"
                                    //, "~/Static/Scripts/jquery.layout-1.3.0.js"
                                    //, "~/Static/Scripts/jquery.layout.state.js"
                                    , "~/Static/Scripts/helper.mainlayout.js"));
    }
}
```

just keep adding your script path in `.Include()` for every javascript in the view and keep doing `bundles.add(new ScriptBundle(<bundle path>))` for every view you have.

you will do the similar steps with CSS bundles, but instead of using `ScripBundle` you will use `StyleBundle`

To lessen the repetition of codes try creating a list of strings for every javascripts that are dependent to one another and do a union on them:

```
List<string> jqGridScripts = new List<string>
                             {"~/Static/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"
                             , "~/Static/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"
                             , "~/Static/Scripts/helper.jqgrid.js"};
List<string> jqStopwatch = new List<string> 
                             { "~/Static/Scripts/jquery.stopwatch.js" };

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/viewName")
                             .Include(jqGridScripts
                                     .Union(jqStopwatch).ToArray()));
```

Just remember that the order in which they appear on the array is the same order in which they will appear on the HTML or be bundled and minified.

**Code in View:**

```
@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/viewName");
}
```

**Resultant Code in HTML**

```
<script src="/WDCSS/bundles/viewName?v=T3IlBuvfGTiz62pwDuiPogFX1jQoxVC2tmp3K6wffBQ1"></script>
```

**My Opinion**

I don't really know if we should do this or not. For me I separate scripts that are used in all pages in a separate bundle so that it would be cached. and then create another bundle for the scripts used in a view. What I am trying to say is that we should achieve a balance between bundling, minification, and caching.